# font-family not showing in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm just trying to add a regular font-family to my website, but IE8 won't display it. It just displays its default Times New Roman. This is my CSS:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

This appears fine on IE7, 9 and obviously Chrome and Firefox but I'm not sure why IE8 is having issues?

My doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

I'm really stuck on this. It's such a simple thing, I'm not sure why IE8 is not liking it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Julie

Comment: Gee not much to go on... Are other styles loading in IE8 ?? Is this IE8 in IE8 standards mode or eg. the latest rendering mode?

Comment: Where is the CSS located?

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache. As nothing is wrong with your code. So cache may be causing the issue.

Comment: In my <head> I have the reset.css first then my style.css, so my style.css should overide certain styles in the reset, but for IE8 it's not. When I remove the 'font-family:inherit' in my reset.css it works fine? I shouldn't have to do this though?

Comment: use the dev tool and see if the font is getting overridden by something else

Comment: @JulieAlchin how can you be sure that style.css will overide reset.css? CSS stands for **Cascading** Style Sheet. You should first learn [Cascading Order and Inheritance in CSS](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css).
Order of the style rules is not the most important rule in css hierarchy. It is probably the least one, though.

Comment: Are you sure you're using reset.css for the right reasons? I've never seen a reset stylesheet that actually addresses the differences in display on different browsers; all they do is turn everything into plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem that was driving me nuts!

Ok, so my scenario was running Drupal 7, with bootstrap and using html5shim.js and respond.js to support media queries etc in ie8

One requirement of this setup is that css aggregation needs to be disabled for Respond to work correctly... Also with bootstrap it is very possible to exceed ie8's 4096 selector limit, so I took care to disable certain components to make sure that I came in under this!

So my problem was that once css aggregation was enabled, despite showing in ie8's (excuse for an) inspector, it always seemed to revert to times new roman, ie8 and other browsers default font!? Disable either respond or css aggregation, and everything works as expected, including the right fonts in ie 8!!!

Ok, so it turns out as mentioned by Julie previously, when I remove font: inherit from the meyer reset, everything seems to work as normal. This is counter intuitive as you would expect css to cascade, and any later values should override an earlier declared one. Also why does font: inherit cause ie8 to ignore fonts even if they are declared later?

So the fix here seems to be to remove font: inherit (which I thought was how css worked anyway), and enable css aggregation and see respond working as expected in ie8!?